# C application special characters Äöü not showing up correctly in MySQL and terminal

Tags: mysql, c, utf-8, locale

I'm trying to set up my C application so it supports special characters such as ÄÖÜ. However, in the terminal and in my MySQL database they do not show up and are replaced with an " ?". I'm using UTF-8 for the entire db and also set the locale in my c application with

setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8");

What can I do to make my application support these characters?

If I set them manually in phpmyadmin, all seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal, while in mysql, you can run this command:

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

Then everything should display properly in your terminal. You might need to do the same in your C application. That will set the encoding for the session.